# How to Use jquery.Validate with a jquery.multiselect Dropdown?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, multi-select

So the situation is this: attempting to add a dropdown box using the [jquery.multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) plugin on a form that current uses the [jquery.validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin that has other fields (text input fields, single text input that has a `float` value range) that all currently validate correctly.

When I attempt to add validation rules I simply cannot get jquery.validate to validate my multiselect dropdown whatsoever.  Here are snippets of my code (all assumes that required plugins are loaded - see below for versions used):

**The HTML:**

```
<form action="some/action" id="myForm" method="POST">
    Input 1: <input type="text" value="" name="input1" maxlength="200" id="input1"><br/>
    Input 2: <input type="text" value="" name="input2" maxlength="100" id="input2"><br/>
    Input 3: <input type="text" value="" name="input3" maxlength="50" id="input3"><br/>
    Select: <select class="someSelect" name="mySelect" id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="some_val1">Some Value</option>
        <option value="some_val2">Some Other Value</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**The Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mySelect').multiselect({
        noneSelectedText: 'Select Something (required)',
        selectedList: 3,
        classes: 'my-select'
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("needsSelection", function(value, element) {
        return $(element).multiselect("getChecked").length > 0;
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("isPercent", function(value, element) {
        return parseFloat(value) >= 0 && parseFloat(value) <= 100;
    });

    $.validator.messages.needsSelection = 'You gotta pick something.';
    $.validator.messages.isPercent = 'Must be between 0% and 100%';

    $('#myForm').validate({
        rules: {
            mySelect: "required needsSelection",
            input1: "required isPercent",
            input2: "required",
            input3: "required"
        },
        errorClass: 'invalid'
    });
});
```

**Versions**
If there's an explicit/known issue with compatibility between the versions, then I may upgrade if that solves the issue, but I've tested using the newest versions for my purposes and it did not seem to solve my issue.

**jQuery**: 1.4.4

**jquery.validate**: 1.9.0

**jquery.multiselect**: 1.8

And, as always, I can provide more information where possible/needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So it seems that the rules I was setting up for the multiselect were indeed being attached to the select, however, since the original select box is `:hidden` by `jquery.multiselect`, `jquery.validate` by default ignores any hidden inputs.

The solution (which is not of my own - a coworker found it) is to use the `ignore` settings for `jquery.validate`. Whatever selector is passed in with the `ignore` setting is put into a jquery `.not()`, so the solution is actually to use a double negative here:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
        mySelect: "required needsSelection",
        input1: "required isPercent",
        input2: "required",
        input3: "required"
    },
    ignore: ':hidden:not("#mySelect")', //Tells it to check the hidden select
    errorClass: 'invalid'
});
```

Phew!

Comment: Its why I always try to post my issues and the solutions to them - glad to have helped! :)

Comment: You helped me, three!   As you said, "Phew"

Comment: Thank you i used your solution, but in case anyone else has problems i had to remove the "required" option from the select list rule because if i did "uncheck all" and then select only one item, then it was failing to validate and i had to select 2 items and then uncheck one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your two select options carry a value.

```
value="some_val1"
```

Try adding an option at the top with a value of nothing and selected:

```
<option selected="" value="">Please Select Something</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to explicitly specify the elements to validate:

```
$("form").children("input, select, textarea").valid()
```

That will validate the hidden select as well.

In fact, the situation I just encountered there was no other way since I wanted to validate by part for a multistep form:

```
 $("form").find("[data-stepIndex='1']").children("input, select, textarea").valid()
```

Hope it helps someone