# Regarding jquery validation on multiple select option

Tags: php, jquery, html

this is my first project I want to put the validation on dropdown input field with multiple selection but its not working.Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#formValidate").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            business: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email:true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true
            },
            image_consulting: {
                required: true
            },
            soft_skill:{
                required: true
            },
            question: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 15
            },
            about_us: true
        },
        errorElement : 'div',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            var placement = $(element).data('error');
            if (placement) {
                $(placement).append(error)
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where's your form?

Comment: hope it will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539430/how-to-use-jquery-validate-with-a-jquery-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: paste your html code also